# How to emulate/spoof keypress event in Haskell?

Tags: events, haskell, gtk, keypress

How to emulate/spoof keypress event in Haskell?

I have an onscreen number keypad in my Gui which I want to use to write into a number of text entrys in the window. The Keypad is made up of button widgets and what I want to do is have the `onButtonClicked` handler send a `keyPressEvent` so that the appropriate char/number is written into the text entry that has focus. I started by looking at `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Events` and made an keypress event

```
Event my1Event = Key True True Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Events.currentTime [] False False False 0xffb1 "KP_1" Nothing
```

I couldn't figure out how to dispatch this event. Anyway it turns out Event is deprecated and should use EventM. I found `widgetEvent :: WidgetClass self => self -> EventM t Bool` in `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Widget`. In the api it says:

Rarely-used function. This function is used to emit the event signals on a widget (those signals should never be emitted without using this function to do so). If you want to synthesize an event though, don't use this function; instead, use mainDoEvent so the event will behave as if it were in the event queue.

So I looked at `mainDoEvent :: EventM t ()` in `Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.General` but am unsure as how to use `EventM` to create a keypress and couldn't find an example of `mainDoEvent` in use. Can anybody advise me how to create a keypress event using `EventM` and pass it to `mainDoEvent` or some other way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: This question is probably more about GTK than Haskell. See [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-General.html#gtk-main-do-event) for the underlying API, which appears to be exposed through a trivial FFI wrapper in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Generating an event is the Wrong Way. Instead, you should insert your text using the appropriate function for your text widget. For example, for `TextBuffer`s, use [textBufferInsertAtCursor](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.0/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Multiline-TextBuffer.html#v%3atextBufferInsertAtCursor).